# NServiceBus 5.2.14 Doesn't Support HTTPS When Using WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 2.8.2

Tags: azure, https, nservicebus, azureservicebus, servicebus

We have an NServiceBus 5.2.14 (which is the latest stable version available) Endpoint. The Endpoint uses the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus Client Library to connect to an Azure Service Bus Queue over HTTPS.

But the attempt to connect fails because NServiceBus version 5.2.14 only has compatibility with WindowsAzure.ServiceBus Client Library Version 2.8.2 which does not support HTTPS Connectivity Mode. Only versions 3.0.0 and higher of WindowsAzure.ServiceBus Client Library Support HTTPS Connectivity Mode. Unfortunately we cannot use 3.0.0 and higher due to the compatibility issue, nor can we use NServiceBus Version 6.0.0 since it's still in it's Beta release.

- So, Is this a known Bug in NServiceBus?
- Has anyone else experienced this?
- If yes, what is the work-around to keep still connect to Azure Securely without using HTTPS?

Thanks,

Ram

Answer (score 1):

The connection is still secure. The HTTP `ConnectivityMode` [says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitymode.aspx)

> HTTP mode. Listeners attempt an HTTP connection followed by an HTTPS connection with the Service Bus service, then wait for messages. This might allow you to more easily work around TCP port constraints.

In regards to NServiceBus 6.0 - it will use NServiceBus Azure Service Bus version 7, which is based on the Microsoft ASB library version 3 and up.

Comment: Have you used this? Do you know if it attempts it for every connection?

Comment: @RalphWillgoss that's MSFT official documentation :)

Comment: HTTPS mode doesn't attempt port 80 like HTTP does, and uses 433 explicitly. HTTP mode will start with 80 and probe 443.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 2.2 of the AzureServiceBus Library, its worth noting that you have to have port 80 open if you have blocked the default TCP port.

The documentation notes that if Http is blocked it will default to Https, this behavior was not observed - you still need port 80 as a control/management port.